# Video Editor, Why there is audio in gap area?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm new in blender video editor. I have seen some tutorials about blender's video editor and I have applied it on a test video clip.
But I saw a strange thing: there is some audio in gap area.[image: There are audio in red rectangle area. Why?]

There are audio in red rectangle area. Why?